# unlisted reserved word?

Tags: php, return-value

I ran into a very strange behaviour in some of our PHP code today.  We have a class for dealing with files.  It's something like this:

```
class AFile {

 //usual constructor, set and get functions, etc.
 //...

  public function save() {
    //do some validation
    //...

    if($this->upload()) { //save the file to disk
      $this->update_db(); //never reached this line
    }
  }

  private function upload() {
     //save the file to disk
     //...
     return ($success) ? true : false;
  }
}
```

It looked pretty normal to us, but the $this->upload() function never returned anything but NULL.  We checked that the correct function was running. We echoed out its return value before it returned. We tried only returning a true value or even a string. Everything was checking out right.  But $this->upload still evaluated to NULL. Also, there was nothing in the logs and ERROR_ALL is on.

In exasperation we changed the function name to foo_upload.  All of a sudden everything worked. "upload" is not in the list of [PHP reserved words](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).  Anyone have any thoughts why a class function named "upload" would fail?

Comment: Did you put an echo inside the upload function?

Comment: Could it be being overridden somewhere?

Comment: @Chacha: We did put an echo inside the upload function. It gave the expected values.

@Greg: the AFile class doesn't have children (yet) so its methods shouldn't be over-ridden.

Comment: Does this kind of thing happen with any class that has a private method named upload?

Comment: @txwikinger: it seems to be specific to AFile.  Hmm.

Comment: Can you provide us with the whole file ? maybe it'd help ? because, with this portion of code... seems OK...

Comment: Install a debugger and step through the code if you're not willing to paste the entire class and how it's called.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the return statement at the end of the upload method is the only return statement in that method.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get null when "calling" upload would be if you had this (trying to access an inexisting property) :

```
if($a = $this->upload) { // => NULL
  $this->update_db(); //never reached this line
}
var_dump($a);
```

instead of this (from OP) (trying to call an existing method):

```
if($a = $this->upload()) { // => true or false
  $this->update_db(); //never reached this line
}
var_dump($a);
```

Did you check you didn't forget the `()` ?

If it's not this, try with error_reporting set to `E_ALL`, and displaying the errors :

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

*(you said "ERROR_ALL is on", so not sure it's what you meant)*

Comment: sorry, I meant error_reporting(E_ALL). The parentheses are present and there are no object vars with the same name.  We did try catching the result of $this->upload() in a $var as you suggest. It didn't make a difference.